# Inline support Chat implementation

Tags: ajax, chat, live, livechat

We are creating a live chat support system. Currently if the visitor clicks on live chat button, a new window opens up and user can talk their. What I am trying to accomplish is to open the chat window inline like this link:
http://anantgarg.com/chat/sampleb.php

Please note that we are building support chat system not peer chat system as the above link intends.

The problem we are facing here is that how we'll be able to access the database which is located on different server (our server) and not on the server where our client's website is located. The above solution can work fine if we are on the same server. 
So, please suggest on how to overcome this hurdle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, for solve your task you may use WebSockets, it support cross-domain connections.

In your case, you may write chat client side and place it on cliet's website, but request from it weill processed by your server with DB access.

### Extend

Of course you can use JSON with WebSockets just as JSON with AJAX. WebSockets is transport - JSON is content passed with this transport.

I write this code when reserarch WebSockets (chat lietn side):

```
function connect(){
    var socket;
    var host = window.location.host;
    var wsUrl = "ws://" + host + "/connect";

    try{
        var socket = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
        message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState);
        socket.onopen = function(){
            message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)');
            //Run "Ping-Pong" for support connection
            setTimeout(pingPong, 5000);
        }

        socket.onmessage = function(msg){
            //Parse server answer from string to JSON object
            var answer = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            if (answer.type == 'message') {
                message('<p class="message">'+answer.user+': '+answer.message);
            }
        }

        socket.onclose = function(){
            message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (Closed)');
        }           

    } catch(exception){
        message('<p>Error'+exception);
    }

    function send(){
        var text = $('#text').val();
        if(text==""){
            message('<p class="warning">Please enter a message');
            return ;    
        }
        try{
            //Send data via JSON
            socket.send('{"type": "message", "message":'+JSON.stringify(text)+'}');
        } catch(exception){
            message('<p class="warning">');
        }
        $('#text').val("");
    }
    var token = 0;
    function pingPong()
    {
        token++;
        try{
            var msg = {'type': 'ping', 'token': token};
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
            setTimeout(pingPong, 5000);
        } catch(exception){
            message('<p class="warning">');
        }

    }

    function message(msg){
        $('#chatLog').append(msg+'</p>');
    }//End message()

    $('#text').keypress(function(event) {
              if (event.keyCode == '13') {
                 send();
               }
    }); 

    $('#disconnect').click(function(){
        socket.close();
    });

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    if(!("WebSocket" in window)){
        $('#chatLog, input, button, #examples').fadeOut("fast");    
        $('<p>Oh no, you need a browser that supports WebSockets. How about <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a>?</p>').appendTo('#container');     
    }else{
        //The user has WebSockets
        connect();
    }
});
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<style type="text/css">
body{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#container{
    border:5px solid grey;
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}
#chatLog{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black; 
}
#chatLog p{margin:0;}
.event{color:#999;}
.warning{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#CCC;
}
</style>
<title>WebSockets Client</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="container">

        <h1>WebSockets Client</h1>

        <div id="chatLog">

        </div>
        <p id="examples">e.g. try 'hi', 'name', 'age', 'today'</p>

        <input id="text" type="text" />
        <button id="disconnect">Disconnect</button>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Also you can use SocketIO library for it, but I dont sure for it cross-domain work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eugene, Can we also use JSON for this instead of WebSockets? Or can we use both?